# Enable KeyDown Event only in active child of a MDI Application c#

Tags: c#, events, keypress, mdi

I've a MDI application with a mainForm and a childForm with KeyPreview set to TRUE. Now in my childForm when I press a key, the program starts the event KeyPressed in both forms. Can I disable the event in the mainForm when the childForm is active?

What i want is thet: when the childForm is Active, only the event in the form should be triggered...

Best regards, Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just add

```
if(ActiveMdiChild != null)
  return;
```

to the beginning of the event handler of the parent window...

Answer (score 0):

answer should be like this

```
    private void mdifrm_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
            // if there's a form keyPreview set to False
            KeyPreview = false; 
        else
            // else set to True
            KeyPreview = true;

    }
```